# How to clear every TextBox inside a GroupBox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I am having problem with emptying every TextBoxes inside a GroupBox, because my loop only clears all TextBoxes if `textbox1` has value but if I try to bypass `textbox1` and jump to input data to `textbox2`, my `ClearCtrlText` method doesn't work.

Please see my loop code if there's a need for change:

```
Public Sub ClearCtrlText(ByVal root As Control)

    For Each ctrl As Control In root.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then ' textbox set to empty string
            If ctrl.Text <> "" Then
                ctrl.Text = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be tempted to write this as an extension method:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module ControlExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Sub ClearTextBoxes(source As Control)
        For Each child As Control In source.Controls
            Dim tb = TryCast(child, TextBox)

            If tb Is Nothing Then
                child.ClearTextBoxes()
            Else
                tb.Clear()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

You can then call it on a control as though it was a member, e.g.

```
GroupBox1.ClearTextBoxes()
```

This method also includes the recursion required to access child controls inside child containers, e.g. a `Panel` inside the `GroupBox`.

Comment: how to add such extension?

Comment: Maybe use your eyes. The code I posted is a module so why would it not be added like any other module?

Comment: Oh sorry for that I thought that is another item to be added as module

Comment: It's a module like any other module. Extension methods must be declared in modules. You can add the method to a module you already have or you can do as I have done here and add a module dedicated to methods that extend the control class.  That's what I tend to do: one module per extended type. Once you have the module and the method declared with the `Extension` attribute, the method is available to call like a member.  I'd suggest some general reading on extension methods as well, so that you understand things like you need to have imported the namespace the module is a member of.

Comment: thanks for your code it works, I saw what I am making mistakes I removed the if statement that validate textbox1 if empty and this is the one making my cleartext function won't work :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to **RECURSE** into containers within the form like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ClearCtrlText(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Sub ClearCtrlText(ByVal root As Control)
        For Each ctrl As Control In root.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then ' textbox set to empty string
                If ctrl.Text <> "" Then
                    ctrl.Text = Nothing
                End If
            ElseIf ctrl.HasChildren Then
                ClearCtrlText(ctrl)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i'll try your answer :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this code is inside a module

Comment: It still bypass other textboxes

Comment: You have to pass in the Form. Shouldn't matter that it's in a module. How is it not working?  Give details about your setup...

Comment: I am using this function to clear textboxes inside a groupbox ie. ClearCtrlText(groupbox1) when i click the cancel button

Comment: That should work. You're not conveying ~something~ about your setup or what you're doing...

Comment: I tried again your code but it still bypass other textboxes if I don't put any value in textbox1

Comment: I've tested it myself. Post YOUR version of the code please.

Comment: As suggested, you need to post the code that you used that didn't work and explain HOW you used it, but please be sure to edit your question and add the code there. Don't try to post long code snippets in comments.

Comment: thanks for your code it works, I saw what I am making mistakes I removed the if statement that validate textbox1 if empty and this is the one making my cleartext function won't work :)